# FlaskSocketIO: I am able to emit socketio messages from client to server, but not vice versa

Tags: python, reactjs, socket.io, flask-socketio, emit

I have a Flask application setup with ReactJS as front-end. The structure of my application is based on miguelgrinberg's [Flask-SocketIO-Chat](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/) app. So the initialization of socketio and the blueprinting of Flask application is all the same as the aforementioned repository, an example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


socketio = SocketIO()


def create_app(debug=False):
    """Create an application."""
    app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='../../static/dist', 
    template_folder='../../static')
    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gjr39dkjn344_!67#'

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    socketio.init_app(app)

    return app
```

So if you look at **Flask-SocketIO-Chat** repo, there is `events.py` in `app/main/` directory which contains all the SocketIO related work. In that I have code that emits message to two namespaces. When I emit the message to `/` endpoint, it works flawlessly, but when I try to emit to `/analysis` endpoint which I have open in another tab. The emit message doesn't get through. Surprisingly, If I emit a message from the client (ReactJS), I am able to catch it in the server (Flask).

Here is how I connect to SocketIO at the client side:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = io('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/analysis');
```

I appreciate any input to this issue. Please let me know if there is any other information required.

-Tayab Soomro.

Comment: Did you enable longs on the client and server to see where are the events getting lost?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about doing that. I did however, check in my Flask server that every time event is triggered in Flask server, the Flask server shows following message:



`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2018 08:34:20] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MKKpsEU&sid=38cd6f6b61c44d54b1cf0855aaecc1b3 HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.000725`

But the client doesn't seem to respond to anything.